# Checking for valid input while using fscanf

Tags: c, linked-list

I was wondering if there is a way to check whether the input of the file is valid, while scanning the content of the file.

For example, if I am to scan a file named filename, I expect the file to contain undefined numbers of sets that contain 5 elements namely Name, Sex, Age, Height, and Weight. I will create a single linked list for this program.

So I will create typedef Struct :

```
typedef struct nodebase{
    char name[20];
    char sex; //M for male and F for female
    int age;
    double height; // Height shall be rounded off to 2 decimal points
    double weight; // Weight shall be rounded off to 2 decimal points
    struct nodebase *next;
}listnode;

int main()
{
    int totalsets; //Counter for total numbers of "sets" within the file
    char filename[20];
    listnode *head;
    listnode *tail;
    listnode *current;
    FILE *flist;

    printf("Type the name of the file for the list: \n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
```

Then while scanning for all the possible "sets" within the file,

```
flist = fopen(filename,"r");
while(!feof(flist))
{
    if(5 == fscanf(flist,"%s[^\n]%c%d%lf%lf",&current->name,&current->sex,&current->age,&current->height,&current->weight)
{
    totalsets++;
}
```

(Here goes my question): How can I make the program tell the user if some of the file input is wrong (but the program will still count for those valid "sets")?

Like if the file has a set that contains integers when it is supposed to be the character for gender

And the other question will be, can the program (after detecting such invalid input) accepts user's edit and overwrite the edit on the invalid input part of the set?

Thank you so much!

*I haven't finished with the entire coding yet. I am stuck in here so I just wanted to complete this part before moving on.
*There might be already answers for my question but frankly speaking, I do not understand them...

I am using VS2012 on Windows.

Comment: Don't use `scanf()`. It's evil. Use `fgets()` to get user input, `strchr()` and `strtod()` to parse it.

Comment: Okay! But I heard that one has to create a buffer when using fgets() since it automatically adds space and enter.

Comment: By the way, can fgets read even the strings with spaces? Such as Full name of a person?

Comment: Usually when faced with similar problems at school (or contest), we scanned the whole line and parsed it (assuming sets are contained one in each line).

Comment: @SungMinKim It can, unlike `scanf()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 What will be the return value of `strstr()` if I used it to check if the "name" part of the list has the string? If the name part has some other thing instead of string, will it return like 0? I need this to use the if() -> `if(the return value of strstr() when invalid data has been acknowledged)...`

Comment: @SungMinKim What did the documentation say about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

```
char buf[256];
while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, flist) != NULL) {
  if(5 == sscanf(buf,"%19s %c%d%lf%lf", &current->name,...)   {
    totalsets++;
  }
}
```

---

Some format changes:

`"%s[^\n]"` is invalid syntax.  `%s` won't scan `\n` anyways.
Use `" %c"` to consume spaces before assigning the sex.

In general you have a syntax problem : how does your file separate name form sex?  A space may appear in a name, or not.  A name may have multiple spaces in it.  The classic idiom is to use comma separated values as below

```
  if(5 == sscanf(buf,"%19[^,] , %c ,%d ,%lf ,%lf", &current->name,...)   {
```

Comment: Hi chux! Thank you so much for helping me numerous of times. I just want to ask if I could use your "fgets" code even for reading the integers of the file?

Comment: What does the comma exactly do? The file will store the data by: (name here) enter (gender here) enter (age here) enter... and so on and the file will be in a .txt format

Comment: Some has suggested to me to use %19[^\n] instead of %s[^\n], assuming that my string will be within 20. Will that also be all right? And for your sscanf, is it reading from the file?

Comment: I would still read integers via `fgets() when encoded as text like "1234".  Use `fgets()` to read a line of text from a file or stdin.  Use its result of NULL to indicate you have EOF or I/O issues.  Use `sscanf()` to parse the buffer into variables and perform syntax checking _always_ checking its result.  (`strtok()` is another approach.)  At the end-of-the-day, you will have done a bit more work, but separating I/O from parsing will save your backside in real world code.  Input is evil and not to be trusted until read error-free, parsed and validated.

Comment: @Sung Min Kim  (what comma will do) Will spaces occur in a name? Say you text is "Sung Min Kim M 25 ..." or "chux M 25 ...".  How to distinguish when the `name` stops and the `sex` begins? A comma would do that: "Sung Min Kim, M, 25, ...".

Comment: Will I still need the comma if I know that the spaces will occur after every "part" of the set, like name [space] sex [space] age [space] ....

Comment: @Sung Min Kim (%19[^\n] v. %s[^\n]).  `%s[^\n]` is _not_ a valid format specifier.  `%19[^\n]` will consume up to 19 `chars` in the line thus making the `name` "Sung Min Kim M 25 1". and not "Sung Min Kim".  `sscanf()` reads from a `char *` (a  string buffer) and not from a file.  `fgets()` read from the file and put the text into `buf`.

Comment: @Sung Min Kim (Will I still need the comma) If spaces are allowed in a name, yes you need some separator like a comma.  If spaces are _not_ allowed in a name `"%19s %c ..."` will work fine.